# How to apply multiple rotations with different angles?

Tags: rotation, java-3d, transformgroup

I'm trying to rotate a few cylinders on the z-axis 90 degrees and then each on the y-axis at varying degrees. My problem is that using the setRotation function only allows me to pick one angle but apply it to multiple axes. If I add another setRotation, it just changes it and doesn't add to it. What can I do to apply multiple rotations, or even multiple or the same transformations to the same object? Here is a snippet of my code showing what I do.

```
Cylinder EtoPeg = new Cylinder(1.5f, 130f, Primitive.GENERATE_NORMALS, paint);
tr = new Transform3D();
tr.setTranslation(new Vector3f((-284f) * (1f / 400), (-23f + 0 * 6) * (1f / 400), (26.24375f + (7 * 10.09375f / 8)) * (1f / 400)));
tr.setScale(1f / 400);
tr.setRotation(new AxisAngle4d(0, 0, 1, Math.PI / 2));
tg = new TransformGroup(tr);
spin.addChild(tg);
tg.addChild(EtoPeg);
```

Answer (score 1):

That’s right, the `setRotation` method resets the rotation aspects of transformation matrix to be a rotation at the angle you specified. To combine rotations, you create `Transform3D` objects that represent the different rotations you want, and then call `mul` to multiply those rotations together (this modifies the `Transform3D` object on which you called `mul`). You probably want to do this with `Transform3D` objects that contain only rotations, because the meaning can get tricky if you start multiplying transforms that contain both rotations and translations.